# Pass-by-reference not working with additional parameters for array_walk_recursive, unless it's the deprecated call-time pass-by-reference

Tags: php, pass-by-reference

For a while now, I've been using a "traditional" recursive function to flatten multi-dimensional arrays such as

```
$baseArray = array(array('alpha'),
                   array('beta','gamma'),
                   array(),
                   array(array('delta','epsilon'),
                         array('zeta',array('eta',
                                            'theta'
                                           ),
                              ),
                        ),
                   array('iota'),
                  );
```

to a simple 1-d array.

Last night, I thought I'd take a look at using [array_walk_recursive()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) to see if I could make it more efficient and cleaner.

My first attempt wasn't very successful:

```
function flattenArray($arrayValue, $arrayKey, &$flatArray) {
    $flatArray[] = $arrayValue;
}


$flattenedArray = array();
array_walk_recursive($baseArray,'flattenArray',$flattenedArray);
```

I thought it should work, but all I got was a series of errors:

```
Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in C:\xampp\htdocs\arrayTest.php on line 16
```

and a result of:

```
array(0) { }
```

Type hinting in my flattenArray() function gave me

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 3 passed to flattenArray() must be an array, integer given in C:\xampp\htdocs\arrayTest.php on line 16
```

Using a closure gave identical results

The only way I could get it to work (without recourse to using a global or a static for my flattenedArray) was using call-time pass-by-reference:

```
function flattenArray($arrayValue, $arrayKey, $flatArray) {
    $flatArray[] = $arrayValue;
}


$flattenedArray = array();
array_walk_recursive($baseArray,'flattenArray',&$flattenedArray);
```

which produces the correct result

```
array(9) { [0]=> string(5) "alpha" [1]=> string(4) "beta" [2]=> string(5) "gamma" [3]=> string(5) "delta" [4]=> string(7) "epsilon" [5]=> string(4) "zeta" [6]=> string(3) "eta" [7]=> string(5) "theta" [8]=> string(4) "iota" }
```

but gives me a not-unexpected warning

```
Deprecated: Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\arrayTest.php on line 22
```

I know PHP is a quirky language, but this seems a bit extreme. The documentation clearly shows that the first parameter to array_walk_recursive is pass-by-reference, but it seems that additional arguments can only be pass-by-reference at call-time. Weird!

PHP version is 5.3.8

Any suggestions as to how I can use array_walk_recursive to flatten my array correctly, without getting deprecated errors (besides filing a bug report).

**EDIT**

P.S.

I am aware that I can bypass this problem using a closure:

```
$flattenedArray = array();
array_walk_recursive($baseArray, function($arrayValue, $arrayKey) use(&$flattenedArray){ $flattenedArray[] = $arrayValue; } );
var_dump($flattenedArray);
```

but as this is required for a library which currently allows use with PHP 5.2.0, it's not a practical option to use a feature that requires a significantly later version of PHP

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Think about it this way: You pass `$flatArray` into `array_walk_recursive` **by value**. `array_walk_recursive` will then further pass the argument **by reference** to your function. But as it was passed to `array_walk_recursive` by value, the reference will already point to a different value.

I know, this might seem like a strange limitation, but when you think about it, it's quite logical too.

By the way, I think you accidentally also found another issue with this, it actually looks like serious memory corruption (look at the third elements of the array printed @ http://codepad.viper-7.com/ZYNrNd). I will look into this.

On a side note, an easy way to flatten is using a `RecursiveArrayIterator`:

```
$flattenedArray = array();
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
             new RecursiveArrayIterator($baseArray),
             RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
         ) as $value) {
    $flattenedArray[] = $value;
}
```

Comment: I can see the logic, though I'm not sure I agree with it... the arrayValue argument is passed to the callback function by reference, allowing the array values to be changed - function changer(&$arrayValue, $arrayKey) {
 $arrayValue .= ' TEST';
}

array_walk_recursive($baseArray,'changer');
var_dump($baseArray);

Comment: The memory corruption issue does strike me as potentially serious though.... hadn't seen any evidence of it till you highlighted it

Comment: I certainly think there should be some formal note indicating that call-by-reference can't be used with additional arguments in the callback function as for call_user_func(), not just any comment that I might add

Comment: @MarkBaker Yes, I am also concerned about the corruption. The numbers look like pointers and if you play around with it (by adding additional code before the var_dump) you can change the pattern. I'll ping #php.pecl about this and see what they say about it.

Comment: @MarkBaker I will add that note as soon as I find time ;)

Comment: Thanks NikiC - now my only concern is performance testing to see what difference array_walk_recursive() using a class atrribute will make compared to a standard recursive flattening mthod.... well, that and php.pecl response

Comment: @MarkBaker btw, concerning your main problem: Why not just use a RecursiveArrayIterator to create that flattened array? (Maybe you can even use the RecursiveArrayIterator directly, depending on your application, but if no that you can at least easily flatten with it.) [I just added an example how to use it.]

Comment: thanks for the suggestion... I'll have to take a look and run some performance tests with large data volumes (the main reason I need to improve performance); but I suspect that both array_walk_recursive() with a class atrribute for the result, and RecursiveArrayIterators will be faster than my current recursive method calls.... have to see how they stack up on memory usage too

Comment: @MarkBaker Completely forgot about this. I now fixed the segfault / memory leak in SVN, so it will be fixed in PHP 5.3.11 / 5.4.1 :)

Comment: Thanks, so I'm already responsible for causing bugs in PHP5.4 less than 24 hrs after its official production release :)

Comment: @MarkBaker No worries, there were already more than 20 fixes in these 24 hours: http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/branches/PHP_5_4/NEWS?view=markup (Okay, admittedly most of those are just backports from trunk caused by the PHP 5.4 code freeze ^^)

Answer (score 1):

Not particularly helpful at this stage.

Reading through the PHP docs, I've found that [call_user_func()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) has a note against it's description of parameter arguments:

> Note that the parameters for call_user_func() are not passed by
>   reference.

but [array_walk_recursive()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) has no such notice.

This may be purely a documentation issue... if I'd seen a similar notice in the array_walk_recursive() documentation, I probably wouldn't have tried it (although the curious might have tried regardless, just to see what happened).

However, I don't understand why either case shouldn't accept pass-by-reference arguments in the callback function definition. This does feel a bit like a step backward.... a language feature that did work (albeit using the call-time pass-by-reference) no longer does so, without relying on that deprecated feature.

Answer (score 1):

Since your solutions are version-specific (according to the documentation, PHP 5.2 shouldn't complain about call-time [pass-by-reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)), one option is to create different scripts containg each implementation, then have another script conditionally include the script that defines the flattening function (and any other version-specific code) depending on the PHP version.

```
if (! defined('PHP_VERSION_ID')) {
    $version = explode('.', PHP_VERSION);
    define('PHP_VERSION_ID', ($version[0] * 10000 + $version[1] * 100 + $version[2]));
    if (PHP_VERSION_ID < 50207) {
        define('PHP_MAJOR_VERSION',   $version[0]);
        define('PHP_MINOR_VERSION',   $version[1]);
        define('PHP_RELEASE_VERSION', $version[2]);
    }
}
if (PHP_VERSION_ID < 50300) {
    include_once('php-5.2-.php');
} else {
    include_once('php-5.3+.php');
}
```

Comment: I'd have to see how that would work, it's not a particularly clean solution, but it might give me some of the performance benefits I need without breaking functionality across PHP versions.... if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0', '<')) { etc

Answer (score 0):

Pass by reference at call time is deprecated:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.allow-call-time-pass-reference

This isn't noted in the array_walk_recursive documentation because it isn't specific to that function.

One thing you could do is pass an object and method name, rather than a function name, as the callback, and maintain the state of the flattened array as a member of that object.

e.g.

```
class ArrayFlattener
{
    //implementation and array state
}

$flattener = new ArrayFlattener();
array_walk_recursive($baseArray, array($flattener, 'flatten'));

print_r($flattener->getFlattenedArray());
```

Comment: I appreciate __call-time__ pass-by-reference is deprecated, but I was trying a straight pass-by-reference which isn't deprecated, but doesn't appear to work when used for __additional__ arguments in a callback function.

Comment: I may have to use a class attribute as a fallback method.... this will be used within a class once I can get it working... but I'll need to ensure that I initialise the attribute whenever I use the flatten method, which is additional overhead